# Php install zip

Tags: php, dll, zip, installation

How do I install zip in my php?
The documentation just said:

> Windows users need to enable php_zip.dll inside of php.ini in order to
>   use these functions.

I searched in my php.ini for php_zip.dll but could not find it.

Thus I searched for tutorials who tell me how to install that .dll but could not found any.

Comment: Where did you get your php from? If your php version does not ship with the required dll you'll need another php distribution or have to compile it your self.

Comment: PHP Version:5.5.11, how excatly do I compile it myself

Comment: How did you install php? Did you use XAMPP or some other software to install it? Solution may depend on you answer.

Comment: I use / installed XAMPP

Answer (score 2):

Download the extension from: http://pecl.php.net/package/zip/1.12.4/windows

Edit you php.ini file and add the line

```
extension=php_zip.dll
```

then restart your web server.

Comment: the problem is that I do not have installed php_zip.dll.

the path:C:\xampp\php\ext does not hold that file

Comment: After download the extension, where does it need to be put? Does it need to be extracted also?

Comment: @Trilarion, not sure what is the directory on Windows, but you can specify on your php.ini using the key `extension_dir`. Take a look at this doc page: https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.windows.php